vue3 Generic component instancetype
<template>
  <div class="record-warpper">
    <div class="history">
      <SessionHistory
        ref="sessionRef"
        v-model:sessionId="sessionId"
      />
    </div>
    <div class="chat-warpper">
      <ChatLib />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
import { SessionHistory, ChatLib } from '@/components';
import { useUrlQuery } from '@/uses';
import { BookType } from '@/types';

const sessionId = ref<number>(1);
/**
Annotation type "<T=string>(__VLS-Pps: Awaited<typeof __VLSsetup>[" props "], __VLS_ctx?: __VLS-Prettify<Pick<Awaited<typeof __VLSsetup>," attrs "|" emit "|" slots ">>, __VLS-pose?: NonNullable<Awaited<typeof __VLSsetup>>[" expose "], __VLSsetup?: Promise<...>)=>VNode<...>&{...}" does not satisfy the constraint "abstract new (... args: any)=>any".
Type "<T=string>(__VLS-Pps: {" onUpdate: sessionId "?: (sessionId: T)=>any; sessionId: T;}&VNodeProps&AllowedWidgetProps&WidgetCustomizing Props, __VLS_ctx?: {...}__ VLS_expose?: (exposed: ShallowUnwrapRef<...>) =>  void, __VLS_setup?: Promise<...>) => VNode<...> & { ...; }” The provided content does not match the signature 'new (... args: any): any'
*/
const sessionRef = ref<InstanceType<typeof SessionHistory> | null>(null);

onMounted(() => {
  console.log(sessionRef.value);
});

useUrlQuery<Pick<BookType, 'id' | 'bookType'>>();
</script>

when i write vue3 project, i want tag Generic Components InstanType. It's error, the error code is below.
const sessionRef = ref<InstanceType | null>(null); not error

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
